# Python: Converting timedelta countdown into an actual date of event

Tags: python, json, timedelta

I scraped a website for sneakers, however, instead of giving a date for the drop it gives a timedelta (length of time until the drop). I am struggling to convert this, I would like it to pinpoint in the embed the date and time of the drop.

Is it possible to convert it? from timedelta, into a UTC date and time?

```
        Date = datetime.strptime(product['launchdate'], "%Y%m%d")
        Date = Date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

JSON:

> {'suggestionGroups': [{'indexName': '1keywords', 'indexTitle': '1keywords', 'suggestions': [{'searchterm': 'dunk', 'nrResults': 114}, {'searchterm': 'dunk low', 'nrResults': 72}, {'searchterm': 'nike dunk', 'nrResults': 113}]}, {'indexName': '3products', 'indexTitle': '3products', 'suggestions': [{'secondId': 'vs0070spoenp1000001', 'name': 'Nike Sportswear Older Kids Dunk High (GS)', '_thumburl': 'https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Thumbs/1000001_Thumb_1404672.jpg', 'currentprice': '70.00000', 'previousprice': '70.00000', 'producturl': 'https://www.prodirectsport.com/SELECT/p/nike-sportswear-older-kids-dunk-high-gs-blue-white-trainers-boys-shoes-1000001/', 'quickref': '1000001', 'launchtimedelta': '12312540', 'launchdate': '20230530'}, {'secondId': 'vs0070spoenp1000004', 'name': 'Nike Sportswear Older Kids Dunk Low (GS)', '_thumburl': 'https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Thumbs/1000004_Thumb_1393208.jpg', 'currentprice': '75.00000', 'previousprice': '75.00000', 'producturl': 'https://www.prodirectsport.com/SELECT/p/nike-sportswear-older-kids-dunk-low-gs-brown-trainers-boys-shoes-1000004/', 'quickref': '1000004', 'launchtimedelta': '12312540', 'launchdate': '20230530'}, {'secondId': 'vs0070spoenp285675', 'name': 'Nike Sportswear Dunk High Retro SE', '_thumburl': 'https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Thumbs/285675_Thumb_1404837.jpg', 'currentprice': '115.00000', 'previousprice': '115.00000', 'producturl': 'https://www.prodirectsport.com/SELECT/p/nike-sportswear-dunk-high-retro-se-monarch-sail-trainers-mens-shoes-285675/', 'quickref': '285675', 'launchtimedelta': '12315420', 'launchdate': '20230601'}]}, {'indexName': '4categories', 'indexTitle': '4categories', 'suggestions': []}]}

I have tried to change the format but I am completely misunderstanding this. I have also tried multiplying by seconds etc but I don't fully understand how long that number represents.

BTW this porduct is in the past.

```
release_time_val = product['launchtimedelta']
release_time = int(release_time_val) * 60 + 946080000 + 604800 


delta = product['launchtimedelta']
time_obj = datetime.strptime(str(delta),'%z:%S%M%H').time()
```

Comment: By going on the website do you have a corresponding drop datetime for one item you get from scrapping ?

Comment: Nope, these are in the past there is none in present as it stands.

Any indication as to how I convert it would be a good start - I assume initially I need to get it into BST time

Comment: If no one incidentally recognizes this time delta format, no documentation is available and not even examples for dates and related time deltas are present I see no way how to solve this mystery.

Comment: It SHOULD be 4 hours prior to the drop so I guess the timedelta should = 4 hours

If we go off that assumption, is it possible?